# calling a package pycharm vs sublime, WindowsOS vs MacOS

Tags: python, pycharm, sublimetext3

I have a project developed in PyCharm and Windows. The project is python based and works fine. The project with the pyCharm editor compiles nicely and works as expected. But when I try to build the project in Sublime/MacOS, It throws out an error - cannot import module.

For an instance, in the attached screenshot you'll see config folder has FrameworkConfig and other scripts. when it is called from Driver.py it throws "import error" in MacOS and/or linux. But works just fine in Windows. What am I missing? Please note that I have properly set up the home directory and is properly pointed.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that you are using python2.7 by accident? Make sure you are executing with `python3 <yourfile>.py`?

Comment: Yes I am in pyton2.7. Any possible ways to get it running with this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your PYTHONPATH and your sys.path, PyCharm use to add project's path to some of them (not sure which one) automatically, so maybe that's why you can not run it using SublimeText. I have been there too.